# Difference between crontab -l and crontab - l

Tags: cron

What is the exact difference between the both the commands crontab -l and crontab - l. is there a difference between them at all?

Answer (score 1):

crontab -l:
            -l stands for list. This displays the crontab of the current user. Since I’m logged in as root, this will display the cron jobs of root user.

Output:

```
53 00 * * 7 /bin/sh /home/root/bin/server-backup
```

crontab - l: No such command available and if you use in command prompt, it does nothing.

Comment: Check Out this blog in order to know more about Crontab https://akhilreddyyalla.blogspot.in/2018/04/what-is-crontabwhat-does-it-do.html